# Set favicon in HTTP server?

Tags: node.js, http, favicon

I'm using Node.js HTTP module to create a server, and I'm wondering, how do I set the favicon (shortcut icon) in a HTTP server? I searched this up, and I saw that Express can set the favicon, but I didn't find any HTTP solution.

How do I accomplish this? (Without migrating to Express)

Comment: You should clarify your question. What do you mean by "setting the favicon"? For me, this means "serving" and apparently @noisypixy thought the same.

Comment: If it's not "serving" the favicon, then I suspect is more related to the HTML side.

Comment: @bjskistad "serving" a favicon, to most people, means allowing it to be served to a client through an HTTP request. That's also what's required to be able to display it in a tab. It's also what the answer to this question implements.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It boils down to this:

- If the requested path is that of your favicon, serve it.
- Otherwise, do whatever you're doing with the requests.

Unless you change the path to your favicon in an HTML document, browsers will (usually) make a request to the `/favicon.ico` path in order to get the favicon of your server.

That means, serving your favicon at `/favicon.ico` is often enough.

Assuming your favicon is located at `./public/favicon.ico`, and will be served at the `/favicon.ico` path in your server, you can do something like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');

var server = http.createServer();

// Location of your favicon in the filesystem.
var FAVICON = path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;

  // If this request is asking for our favicon, respond with it.
  if (req.method === 'GET' && pathname === '/favicon.ico') {
    // MIME type of your favicon.
    //
    // .ico = 'image/x-icon' or 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon'
    // .png = 'image/png'
    // .jpg = 'image/jpeg'
    // .jpeg = 'image/jpeg'
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/x-icon');

    // Serve your favicon and finish response.
    //
    // You don't need to call `.end()` yourself because
    // `pipe` will do it automatically.
    fs.createReadStream(FAVICON).pipe(res);

    return;
  }

  // This request was not asking for our favicon,
  // so you can handle it like any other request.

  res.end();
});

// Listen on port 3000.
//
// This line is not relevant to this answer, but
// it would feel incomplete otherwise.
server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: @bjskistad I find this answer reasonable, even if that's not what you want. If you downvote it, I advice you to undo this.

Comment: I edited it to be more beginner-friendly, just in case. I don't particularly mind the downvoting though.

Comment: Not sure if serious.

Comment: thnxxx.... worked perfectly after searching for half an hour...